# How to Disable Visual Studio 2010 windows changing when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide

When I'm working in VS.Net 2010, then start debugging, seems like a new window profile or something like that kicks in and rearranges/hides windows that I had open previously.  Is there any way to disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this cannot be disabled.

What you can do to work around it a bit though is the following

1. Start a debugging session
2. Arrange the windows to your liking
3. Stop the debugging session
4. Close Visual Studio

After this point whenever you start a debugging session it will return to the window arrangument you had at step #2.